# How can I create a colormap with a fixed color for 0 in R / ggplot

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

I am producing heatmaps of measurement using `ggplot2`. The data contains positive and negative values and I use the `rainbow()` palette for coloring.

I have different data sets and would like to scale the colora in a way that the minimum, maximum and 0 values of each data set get the same colors assigned. I could only find out to set the minimum and maximum using `limits=...`

How can I also define a given color for 0?

Here is my minimal example, if I would for example use rainbow(5), I would like the 3rd color to be the zero color.

```
data <- read.csv("http://protzkeule.de/data.csv")
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=variable, y=meas)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=value)) + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rev(rainbow(255)),limits=c(-.2,.4))
```

Comment: have you looked at [the examples](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/scale_gradientn.html)? (in particular, using the `values` and `rescale` parameters

Comment: from the examples I understand how to make the scale symmetric (it is the same like setting symmetric limits right?).
But I don't want the positive and the negative scale to be symmetric, I want them to extend from min() to max() but with having always the same color for 0 even if the range changes, for example in a different data set.

Comment: I found out that in `scale_fill_gradient2()` I am able to define colours for `low`, `high` and `mid`.
I even tried to pass more than one colour to `low` and `high` which worked but I am not sure if that is by accident as it "moves" the mid color as soon as you pass let's say 1 color to `low` and 3 to `high`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a different approach: For my plots I found it easier to cut the values used for the Colors:

```
ggplot(...) +
stat_bin2d (aes(fill=ifelse(..count..>20,20,..count..)), bins = 10) +
scale_fill_gradientn("Count", colours=c("blue", "yellow", "red")) + ...
```